# How to vertically align text over an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a set of tiles: image, small caption text over it and on a mouse hover it shows an extended description.

Each tile will be generated randomly so I don't know exactly what height/width it will be.

My issue is: I want to have a vertically aligned extended description text, but I can't  figure out how to achieve it. Any help is appreciated!

I have a demo here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mezbzL

p.s.
I use Foundation 5.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <ul class="small-block-grid-4">
      <li class="item">
        <div class="item-wrapper">
          <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/380x250">
          <div class="item-caption">Caption text</div>
          <div class="item-desc">
            <span class="item-desc-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod aperiam</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <div class="item-wrapper">
          <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/280x450">
          <div class="item-caption">Caption text</div>
          <div class="item-desc">
            <span class="item-desc-text">Long</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.item-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  &:hover { 
    .item-caption {
      display: none;
    }
    .item-desc {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      margin: auto;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) none repeat scroll 0 0;
      color: white;
      padding: 0 7.5px;
    }
  } 
}

.item-caption {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 7.5px;
}

.item-desc {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text-align: center;` for `.item-caption` and `.item-desc` + `display: flex`.

New CSS:

```
      .item-caption {
          background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) none repeat scroll 0 0;
          color: white;
          width: 100%;
          height: 25px;
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 0;
          left: 0;
          padding: 0 7.5px;
          text-align: center
        }

        .item-desc {
          display: block;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          position: absolute;
          margin: auto;
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) none repeat scroll 0 0;
          color: white;
          padding: 0 7.5px;
          text-align: center;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
    }
  } 
}
```

And if you want it on the top remove `bottom: 0` and put `top: 0` instead.

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/yYRyQx)

Answer (score 1):

Add this :

```
.item-desc {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/McQuinTrix/pen/QjZwor)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` for `item-desc`.

That is way more supported than the flex layout.